# Error Injecting Multiple Libraries into Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-class

I'm getting a weird conflict when using `ng-class` with either of the ternary operators:

```html
<div ng-class="{'red': showDebug, 'blue': !showDebug}" >{{showDebug}}</div>
<div ng-class="showDebug ? 'red' : 'blue'" >{{showDebug}}</div>
```

Whereas both of these work fine on their own:

```html
<div ng-class="{'red': showDebug}" >{{showDebug}}</div>
<div ng-class="{'blue': !showDebug}" >{{showDebug}}</div>
```

I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at updateClasses (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:18307:22)
at Object.ngClassWatchAction [as fn] (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:18318:15)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:12447:29)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:12712:24)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:18980:21)
at https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:2823:10
at Array.forEach (native)
at forEach (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:325:11)
at HTMLAnchorElement.eventHandler (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:2822:5) angular.js:9997
```

[**Demo in Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/fwkF3NnHjkfDh5rhyB6h?p=preview)
<sup>Click on the Debug link.  The debug statements above it should change color</sup>

Oddly, this appears related to how I've initialized my module and controller.  I'm using both [ui.bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and [toaster](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster)

**This will work, but won't bring in toaster**:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.showDebug = true;
});
```

**This doesn't work**:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap', 'toaster']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, toaster) {
  $scope.showDebug = true;
});
```

**I've also tried to inject toaster straight into the controller itself, but still doesn't resolve any conflicts**:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap', 'toaster']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'toaster', function($scope, toaster) {
  $scope.showDebug = true;
}]);
```

It took me a while to even get to the point where I've isolated down these components, but now I'm pretty stuck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be an incompatibility problem either with `ngAnimate` or `toaster` with version of angular you are using.

If you rollback angular to version `1.2.12` the errors disappear.

I would check for more current versions of both, or check github issue tracker for toaster

**Update:** realized after I wrote this that `ngAnimate` being used is a much lower version than angular core.

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/SZTQyX958OlHNMjhS1VF?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

If you use Firefox developer toolbar, you can see the actual error:

```
Error: $animate.setClass is not a function
updateClasses@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:18307:13
ngClassWatchAction@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:18318:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:12447:23
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:12712:13
ngEventHandler/<@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:18980:15
createEventHandler/eventHandler/<@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:2823:7
forEach@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:325:7
createEventHandler/eventHandler@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:2822:5
```

So it's an issue with `$animate` and `toaster`. A simple fix is to update the `ngAnimate` version align with Angular version, using `1.2.20` for both.

```
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-animate.min.js" ></script>
```